# Use of T menus for text editing in mobile

Tags: design-patterns, menu, touch-screen, mobile-text-entry, mobile-text-editing

There is a very interesting article on the '[invisible' problem](https://jenson.org/text/) of editing text on mobile that highlights the lack of novel and tailored UI design patterns for text editing.

In particular, the idea of a T menu that uses swipe gestures for cut and paste, which has no hierarchy and can slide off the screen seems to be a nice improvement for touch input in confined spaces.

Are there any usability or accessibility issues that would make it not appropriate for mobile devices? Or is it the usual "it's not important/cool enough" excuse?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a ton of user research on "marking menus" that has shown them to be great for discovery and repeated use. However, there has never been any Mobile OS implementations that I know of. The design of the Eloquent menu (from the linked paper) was designed to be a simplified version of marking menus, kind of a one-button-mouse vs 3-button-mouse type of approach (btw, I'm the author of that linked paper)